# Design bug in Editing Review, Notifications don't disappear

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, editing, suggested-edits

Unfortunately, I've foolishly closed the tab before I thought to take a screen shot.

I saw a link beneath a question, `edit (1)`, and clicked on it. A notification popped up saying something like that the edit has already been approved.

This notification didn't disappear, clicking the link again gave me another one, about 300 pixels below the first one. Subsequent clicking gave me more, exactly on top of the second one (thicker shadow).

I'm sorry about tha vague description. I never see these notifications, so it's hard to reproduce (maybe somebody could help me out with that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about this - a fix has been deployed.